# How do I create an Array List of a special type?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have designed and written a class of my own called FrequencyData:

```
public class FrequencyData {
    char letter;
    int frequency;

    public FrequencyData(char in_pointer, int in_frequency) {
        frequency = in_frequency;
        letter = in_pointer;
    }

    public char getLetter() {
        return letter;
    }

    public int getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }
}
```

I know how to create an instance of my class:

```
FrequencyData info = new FrequencyData('c', 5);
```

How do I create an Array List and add this instance to it, and other instances later?

Comment: This is not a new question on S.O. by any means. Try searching on how to initialize a generic ArrayList.

Comment: @NathanHughes when you edit a question using the suggested edit mechanism please fix all the issues with the post. Signature and saluations, code a long way from where it's talked about etc. I would have rejected your edit as too minor but others approved it before I could

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're talking about templating the ArrayList class with members of type FrequencyData in java,

```
FrequencyData info = new FrequencyData('c', 5);
ArrayList<FrequencyData> list = new ArrayList<FrequencyData>();
list.add(info);
```

Read up at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Comment: I would recommend using the interface and not restricting your program to an implementation type. 

`List<FrequencyData> list = new ArrayList<FrequencyData>();`